# Neural Networks - Softmax Cross Entropy Loss Decrease Corresponds to Accuracy Decrease

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, softmax

I've been training a neural network and using Tensorflow.
My cost function is:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
```

Training my neural network has caused the cross entropy loss to decrease from ~170k to around 50, a dramatic improvement. Meanwhile, my accuracy has actually gotten slightly worse: from 3% to 2.9%. These tests are made on the training set so overfitting is not in the question.

I calculate accuracy simply as follows:

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: batch_x, y: batch_y}))
```

What could possibly be the cause for this?
Should I use the accuracy as a cost function instead since something is clearly wrong with the cross entropy (softmax) for my case.

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728895/why-is-it-possible-to-have-low-loss-but-also-very-low-accuracy-in-a-convolutio) to this on StackOverflow but the question was never answered completely.

Comment: How many complete runs did you do? Did you only run it twice? If so, is it is probably just a bad run. How many input features do you have and how big is your network? Do you apply a sigmoid and/or another activation function as the last operation in your network? If you, remove it because tensorflow automatically applies softmax. Try to confirm some of these and give us an update!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you figured it out? My loss goes from high to very low, but accuracy remains around 10% for a 10-class classification.

Comment: Okay, in my case the problem was related to the weight initialization. When I started using `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` with `xavier` weight initialization the problem did go away.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell the exact reason for the problem without seeing your machine learning problem.
Please at least provide the type of the problem (binary, multi-class and/or multi-label)

But, with such low accuracy and large difference between accuracy and loss, I believe it is a bug, not a machine learning issue.

One possible bug might be related to loading label data `y`. 3% accuracy is too low for most machine learning problems (except for the image classification). You would get 3% accuracy if you are guessing randomly over 33 labels.
Is your problem really 33 multi-class classification problem? If not, you might have done something wrong when creating data `batch_y` (wrong dimension, shape mismatch to `prediction`, ...).

Comment: Actually yes, my problem is 49 multi-class classification problem. I checked the y label data, it seems fine.

Comment: Ok, but I still think it is a bug. Guessing alll labels wrong in 44 multi-class classification gave me 164.37 loss. There is something wrong with your "~170k loss"